# How to correctly guess the initial points in LogLog plot linear regression?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I have 5 sets of data represented in 5 distinct colored errorbars in the following code (I have not shown caps). `errorbar plot` is shown in logarithmic scale in both axes. Using `curvefit`, I am trying to find the best linear regression passing through these errorbars. However, it seems the power-law equation I have defined to fit is not easily able to find the best-fit slope of the 5 lines. My expectation is that all 5 colored lines should be straight with negative slopes. I had hard time figuring out which starting point *p0* should I specify in curve fitting process. Even with my initial hard-to-guess values, I still don't get all straight lines and some of them are too off from my points. What is the issue here?

[image: my plot]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x_mean = [2.81838293e+20, 5.62341325e+20, 1.12201845e+21, 2.23872114e+21, 4.46683592e+21, 8.91250938e+21, 1.77827941e+22]

mean_1 = [52., 21.33333333, 4., 1., 0., 0.,  0.]
mean_2 = [57., 16.66666667, 5.66666667, 2.33333333, 0.66666667, 0., 0.33333333]
mean_3 = [67.33333333, 20., 8.66666667, 3., 0.66666667, 1., 0.33333333]
mean_4 = [79.66666667, 25., 8.33333333, 3., 1., 0., 0.]
mean_5 = [54.66666667, 16.66666667, 8.33333333, 2., 2., 1., 0.]

error_1 = [4.163332, 2.66666667, 1.15470054, 0.57735027, 0., 0., 0.]
error_2 = [4.35889894, 2.3570226, 1.37436854, 0.8819171, 0.47140452, 0., 0.33333333]
error_3 = [4.7375568, 2.5819889, 1.69967317, 1., 0.47140452, 0.57735027, 0.33333333]
error_4 = [5.15320828, 2.88675135, 1.66666667, 1., 0.57735027, 0., 0.]
error_5 = [4.26874949, 2.3570226, 1.66666667, 0.81649658, 0.81649658, 0.57735027, 0.]


newX = np.logspace(20, 22.3)
def myExpFunc(x, a, b):
    return a*np.power(x, b)

popt_1, pcov_1 = curve_fit(myExpFunc, x_mean, mean_1, sigma=error_1, absolute_sigma=True, p0=(4e31,-1.5))
popt_2, pcov_2 = curve_fit(myExpFunc, x_mean, mean_2, sigma=error_2, absolute_sigma=True, p0=(4e31,-1.5))
popt_3, pcov_3 = curve_fit(myExpFunc, x_mean, mean_3, sigma=error_3, absolute_sigma=True, p0=(4e31,-1.5))
popt_4, pcov_4 = curve_fit(myExpFunc, x_mean, mean_4, sigma=error_4, absolute_sigma=True, p0=(4e31,-1.5))
popt_5, pcov_5 = curve_fit(myExpFunc, x_mean, mean_5, sigma=error_5, absolute_sigma=True, p0=(4e31,-1.5))


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,5))
ax1.errorbar(x_mean, mean_1, yerr=error_1, ecolor = 'magenta', fmt= 'mo', ms=0, elinewidth = 1, capsize = 0, capthick=0)
ax1.errorbar(x_mean, mean_2, yerr=error_2, ecolor = 'red', fmt= 'ro', ms=0, elinewidth = 1, capsize = 0, capthick=0)
ax1.errorbar(x_mean, mean_3, yerr=error_3, ecolor = 'orange', fmt= 'yo', ms=0, elinewidth = 1, capsize = 0, capthick=0)
ax1.errorbar(x_mean, mean_4, yerr=error_4, ecolor = 'green', fmt= 'go', ms=0, elinewidth = 1, capsize = 0, capthick=0)
ax1.errorbar(x_mean, mean_5, yerr=error_5, ecolor = 'blue', fmt= 'bo', ms=0, elinewidth = 1, capsize = 0, capthick=0)

ax1.plot(newX, myExpFunc(newX, *popt_1), 'm-', label='{:.2f} \u00B1 {:.2f}'.format(popt_1[1], pcov_1[1,1]**0.5))
ax1.plot(newX, myExpFunc(newX, *popt_2), 'r-', label='{:.2f} \u00B1 {:.2f}'.format(popt_2[1], pcov_2[1,1]**0.5))
ax1.plot(newX, myExpFunc(newX, *popt_3), 'y-', label='{:.2f} \u00B1 {:.2f}'.format(popt_3[1], pcov_3[1,1]**0.5))
ax1.plot(newX, myExpFunc(newX, *popt_4), 'g-', label='{:.2f} \u00B1 {:.2f}'.format(popt_4[1], pcov_4[1,1]**0.5))
ax1.plot(newX, myExpFunc(newX, *popt_5), 'b-', label='{:.2f} \u00B1 {:.2f}'.format(popt_5[1], pcov_5[1,1]**0.5))
ax1.legend(handlelength=0, loc='upper right', ncol=1, fontsize=10)

ax1.set_xlim([2e20, 3e22])
ax1.set_ylim([2e-1, 1e2])
ax1.set_xscale("log")
ax1.set_yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

Comment: First: try to scale your data. Divide `x` by `1e21` and you basically do not need an initial guess anymore. The true `a,b` you get later by simple error propagation. Second: if working with errors, having some on zero, where the function can actually achieve a perfect match by putting `a = 0` is not a good idea. If this is a measurement, I am quite sure there is a relative and an absolute error of the measurement such that a zero signal has a zero relative error of course, but the total error is definitively greater than zero. What would that be?

Comment: FInal tip: make the `mean, popt` etc dictionaries. Like this you can loop over this and avoid repeating code in the fitting as well as plotting.

Comment: In regards to your first suggestion, it seems that I still do need to specify p0's but I guess I am not quite understanding your discussion of errorbars. Where there is NaNs for errorbars, indeed I have no data available from experiment but I think you're saying that I should increase the size of errorbar to (-inf, inf) due to lack of constraints. Right? Would you mind sharing a code in which you are applying what you're saying?

Comment: Here is the symptoms before applying your suggestion about constraints: py:734: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  transform = 1.0 / sigma
/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:808: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)

Comment: Hi, in what I reproduced here, everything is working reasonable if no errors are considered. If you put a zero value with zero error is it that you actually mean "no data"? That makes a huge difference. As the error is used as weighting, a zero error is infinite weighting; this is not meaningful. A point with no error would be a constraint.  So is it that the zero values should actually be removed from the list as "no data available"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your numbers for X are way too enormous. Maybe you can try taking the log of both sides and fit that? Such as:

log Y = log(a) + b*log(X)

You won’t even need curve_fit at that point, it’s a standard linear regression.

**EDIT**

Please see my rough and not very well checked implementation (**NOTE**: I only have Python 2, so adjust to fit):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as optimize

x_mean = [2.81838293e+20, 5.62341325e+20, 1.12201845e+21, 2.23872114e+21, 4.46683592e+21, 8.91250938e+21, 1.77827941e+22]

mean_1 = [52., 21.33333333, 4., 1., 0., 0.,  0.]
mean_2 = [57., 16.66666667, 5.66666667, 2.33333333, 0.66666667, 0., 0.33333333]
mean_3 = [67.33333333, 20., 8.66666667, 3., 0.66666667, 1., 0.33333333]
mean_4 = [79.66666667, 25., 8.33333333, 3., 1., 0., 0.]
mean_5 = [54.66666667, 16.66666667, 8.33333333, 2., 2., 1., 0.]

error_1 = [4.163332, 2.66666667, 1.15470054, 0.57735027, 0., 0., 0.]
error_2 = [4.35889894, 2.3570226, 1.37436854, 0.8819171, 0.47140452, 0., 0.33333333]
error_3 = [4.7375568, 2.5819889, 1.69967317, 1., 0.47140452, 0.57735027, 0.33333333]
error_4 = [5.15320828, 2.88675135, 1.66666667, 1., 0.57735027, 0., 0.]
error_5 = [4.26874949, 2.3570226, 1.66666667, 0.81649658, 0.81649658, 0.57735027, 0.]


def powerlaw(x, amp, index):
    return amp * (x**index)
    
# define our (line) fitting function
def fitfunc(p, x):
    return p[0] + p[1] * x   

def errfunc(p, x, y, err):
    out = (y - fitfunc(p, x)) / err
    out[~np.isfinite(out)] = 0.0
    return out

pinit = [1.0, -1.0]
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)

for indx in range(1, 6):

    mean = eval('mean_%d'%indx)
    error = eval('error_%d'%indx)
    logx = np.log10(x_mean)
    logy = np.log10(mean)
    logy[~np.isfinite(logy)] = 0.0
    logyerr = np.array(error) / np.array(mean)
    logyerr[~np.isfinite(logyerr)] = 0.0

    out = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, pinit, args=(logx, logy, logyerr), full_output=1)

    pfinal = out[0]
    covar = out[1]
    
    index = pfinal[1]
    amp = 10.0**pfinal[0]

    indexErr = np.sqrt(covar[0][0] ) 
    ampErr = np.sqrt(covar[1][1] ) * amp

    ##########
    # Plotting data
    ##########

    ax1.plot(x_mean, powerlaw(x_mean, amp, index), label=u'{:.2f} \u00B1 {:.2f}'.format(pfinal[1], covar[1,1]**0.5))     # Fit
    ax1.errorbar(x_mean, mean, yerr=error, fmt='k.', label='__no_legend__')  # Data
    ax1.set_title('Best Fit Power Law', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
    ax1.set_xlabel('X', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    ax1.grid()

    ax2.loglog(x_mean, powerlaw(x_mean, amp, index), label=u'{:.2f} \u00B1 {:.2f}'.format(pfinal[1], covar[1,1]**0.5))
    ax2.errorbar(x_mean, mean, yerr=error, fmt='k.', label='__no_legend__')  # Data
    ax2.set_xlabel('X (log scale)', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Y (log scale)', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    ax2.grid(b=True, which='major', linestyle='--', color='darkgrey')
    ax2.grid(b=True, which='minor', linestyle=':', color='grey')


ax1.legend()
ax2.legend()
plt.show()
```

Picture:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it seems that even doing that is not taking care of the presence or absence of data given the important of constraints. Would you mind implementing your suggestion to see what I mean?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand: what kind of presence/absence of data are we talking about? Which constraints?

Comment: How would you modify these two lines in python3?  mean = eval('mean_%d'%indx)
    error = eval('error_%d'%indx) I am not sure what you mean by them!

Comment: It’s a way to quickly grab the values of mean_1, mean_2, etc... and error_1, error_2 and so on. You don’t need me to modify these lines, this is basic Python and there’s tons of ways to do it (maybe make a 2D numpy array to store errors and means?). My approach is a quick and dirty solution, with an unorthodox tool (eval). And I don’t care, it works, and it can easily be modified.

Comment: And “eval” works in Python 3 too as far as I know...